# Azure AD best practice -should I keep using a single registration for multiple apps?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

A newbie question I am afraid: we have used the same 2 registrations for 2 separate apps and 2 separate APIs:

- Reg1: App1 and App2
- Reg2: API1 and API2

It works and it is possible since each registration allows multiple redirect URLs.

However it does not seem right to me and I believe each App and API should have its own registration. I am not a regular IAM practitioner and I fail to find compelling arguments to why we should not do it.   Could someone either confirm it is OK or provide reasons why we should not do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each app should have its own registration. Some reasons:

- You cannot create a service principal that has access to App1 and not App2
- App1 probably requires or will require different permissions than App2 - if a company only want to use App1, it will have to consent to permissions that the application (app1) doesn't need
- The number of redirect URIs are limited. See [Maximum number of redirect URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#maximum-number-of-redirect-uris)
- [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)